# Get Specific Value Of Every Object From A List of JSON Objects

Tags: c#, list, json.net

in a task that i'm doing to make a report using information from a JSON string, in my learning of C# language, I have to do the following:

- Transform the JSON string into object (done).
- Create a list adding all objects (done).
- Get a specific value from every object of the  (pending).

So, for example, this is what i got so far

```
string json = @"{
'Name': 'Main Bank',
'Register_Date': '2018-4-7',
'CEO': 'John Peterson}";

Bank bank = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bank>(json);
List<Bank> bank_list = new List<Bank>();
bank_list.add(bank);
//adding many Bank object to the list

/*what I need here is to get every 'Register_Date' from every object, 
using for each i presume, I don't have this part clear*/
```

I'm open to your suggestions to finish my process, I hope you can give a hand with. Thank you so much for your time and attention.

Comment: you only want the records which have Register_Date?

Comment: Yes sir, only Register_Date records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `Select`

```
var dates = bank_list.Select(x => x.Register_Date).ToList();
```